# How to Export react-native expo app to an older version of android OS?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

How to export the APK file from a react-native application using expo that supports an older version of android OS like Android 4 or 5.

I exported the application, but it doesn't support in Android 4.

Can someoneh help me please, thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the `/android/app/build.gradle` theres a line called `minSdkVersion` inside the `defaultConfig` block, inside the `android` block

[image]

Change the minSdkVersion by accord with [this](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) link.

In your case change to `14` to match with the android 4 SDK version.

I dont use expo, but i guess you can acess this file to change it.